# Is there a way to find the day / night frontier plot on Earth for a given time?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, numerical-methods, coordinate-systems

I am trying to get all the latitudes and longitudes of the limit between day and night on Earth. You can see what I mean [here](http://www.solarsystemscope.com/daylightmap/).

All I could find are ways to get the date and time of a sunset / sunrise for a given location, but I'm trying to do the opposite.

It seems that it would be some periodic function with a changing phase, sadly I don't really know how to find it, or even if it exists ?

Comment: I was trying to do similar once, I realised that what was very simple was that half of the Earth facing away from the Sun was dark - However the obvious co-ordinate system of that sphere is not the same as the one we use with out North & South poles, which are inclined to the vertical axis - I wa trying to work out how to transform spherical coordinates from one set of axes to another - was going to assume a spherical earth and circular orbit initially.  Anyway the boundary between night and day will presumably be a great arc on a sphere, so I'm convinced that exists -

Comment: if you look at the map with the 'harmonic wave'  - that is actually a straight line - it goes across North America, down skimming Africa, misses antarctica, then comes up through the pacific back to America - I say straight line, it is straight if you are on it, it is actually a great arc on the earths surface.  The map is a 'projection' of the spherical earth onto a flat surface